# Outlook Tracker for shared mailbox

Tags: vba, email, outlook

We use a shared outlook mailbox, we receive 1000 emails daily, is there any macro which would provide us the details of item replied at what time and those items which were not replied. Basicallly we need to track the time taken to reply a particular inbox item.

Answer (score 4):

There is no macro, but you can write your own. Outlook -> Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor.

In VBA, you have to start an Outlook.MAPIFolder object and hook it up to the desired mailbox.

```
Dim f As MAPIFolder

Dim olns As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set f = olns.Folders("Mailbox - Name, Name")
Set f = f.Folders("Inbox")
```

If you are examining a subfolder within the mailbox, you'll need to do this:

```
Set f = f.Folders("Name of the subfolder")
```

Then you need to iterate through the items.

```
Dim m As MailItem
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Do Until i > f.Items.Count
    If f.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
        Set m = f.Items(i)
    End If

    ' yada yada

    i = i + 1
    DoEvents
Loop
```

How you detect which have been replied to will depend on what version of Outlook you are using. For Outlook 2007, you can use [Outlook.PropertyAccessor](http://www.outlookbanter.com/outlook-vba/97898-mailitem-object-has-no-property.html). For earlier versions, you can use a third-party add-in like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), or you can resort to something like comparing m.LastModificationTime and m.CreationTime.

For example:

```
        If m.LastModificationTime - m.CreationTime < 0.1 Then
            n = n + 1
            Debug.Print m.subject
        End If
```

The times will always be a little tiny bit off, so you can't use "=", you have to check whether the difference is really small.

This may pick up emails which are forwarded as well as emails which are replied to; consider whether this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still actual, I'd suggest to use Excel's Power Query to track conversations. Basically, all you need is to aggregate your list of items by `Conversation ID` and then take `Received Time` of first and second items of each conversation. Make sure to sort nested tables either by `Received Time` or `Conversation Index`.