# Use Excel VBA to search specific outlook inbox in multi-inbox environment

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have tried search a bunch of forums but have not been able to find a solution to my problem. I will admit that my understanding of VBA objects is limited. I have an Excel VBA report that creates an Outlook object and then scans the Outlook default inbox until it finds an unread email.  I have gotten the code to work perfectly on my computer.  However, the computer that will run this has two (2) different email addresses/inboxes tied to Outlook (One is a personal inbox, and the other is group inbox).

The code I have been using to search my personal inbox is this (it continues on to search for unread emails, etc...):

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlAtch As Object
    '~~> New File Name for the attachment
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = "ActInv Export"
    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

However, this only points to the default inbox (ie the personal email).  How do I change it to set the object to search the group email inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure (since I'm not on a computer running Outlook right now and thus can't play around with it), but I think the answer to your question might be contained in the answer to [this question on building a tracker for a shared Outlook mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567890/outlook-tracker-for-shared-mailbox).

I'm thinking the key lies in the line

`Set f = olns.Folders("Mailbox - Name, Name")`

which is parallel to but different from your statement

`Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`

Good luck!